# Why is adding one operation causing my number of logic elements to skyrocket?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I'm designing a 464 order FIR filter in Verilog for use on the Altera DE0 FPGA. I've got (what I believe to be) a working implementation; however, there's one small issue that's really actually given me quite a headache. The basic operation works like this: A 10 bit number is sent from a micro controller and stored in datastore. The FPGA then filters the data, and lights LED1 if the data is near 100, and off if it's near 50. LED2 is on when the data is neither 100 nor 50, or the filter hasn't filled the buffer yet.

In the specification, the coefficients (which have been pre provided), have been multiplied by 2^15 in order to represent them as integers. Therefore, I need to divide my final output Y by 2^15. I have implemented this using a shift, since it should be (?) the most efficient way. However, this **single** line causes my number of logic elements to jump from ~11,000 without it, to over 35,000. The Altera DE0 uses a Cyclone III FPGA which only has room for about 15k logic elements. I've tried doing it inside both combinational and sequential logic blocks, both of which have the same exact issue.

Why is this single, seemingly simple operation causing such an inflation elements? I'll include my code, which I'm sure isn't the most efficient, nor the cleanest. I don't care about optimizing this design for performance or area/density **at all**. I just want to be able to fit it onto the FPGA so it'll run. I'm not very experienced in HDL design, and this is by far the most complex project I've needed to tackle. It's worth noting that I do not remove y completely, I replace the "bad" line with `assign YY = y;`.

Just as a note: I haven't included all of the coefficients, for sanity's sake. I know there might be a better way to do it than using case statements, but it's the way that it came and I don't really want to relocate 464 elements to a parameter declaration, etc.

```
module lab5 (LED1, LED2, handshake, reset, data_clock, datastore, bit_out, clk); 

    // NUMBER OF COEFFICIENTS (465)
    //  (Change this to a small value for initial testing and debugging, 
    //  otherwise it will take ~4 minutes to load your program on the FPGA.)
    parameter NUMCOEFFICIENTS = 465;

    // DEFINE ALL REGISTERS AND WIRES HERE
    reg         [11:0]  coeffIndex;     // Coefficient index of FIR filter
    reg signed  [16:0]  coefficient;    // Coefficient of FIR filter for index coeffIndex
    reg signed  [16:0]  out;            // Register used for coefficient calculation
    reg signed [31:0] y;
    wire signed [7:0] YY;
    reg [9:0] xn [0:464];               // Integer array for holding x
    integer i;
    output reg LED1, LED2;
    // Added values from part 1
    input reset, handshake, clk, data_clock, bit_out;
    output reg [9:0] datastore;
    integer k; 
    reg sent;

    initial
    begin
        sent = 0;
        i=0;
        datastore = 10'b0000000000;
        y=0;
        LED1 = 0;
        LED2 = 0;
        for (i=0; i<NUMCOEFFICIENTS; i=i+1)
        begin
            xn[i] = 0;
        end
    end


always@(posedge data_clock)
begin
    if(handshake)
    begin
        if(bit_out)
        begin
            datastore = datastore >> 1; 
            datastore [9] = 1;
        end
        else
        begin
            datastore = datastore >> 1;
            datastore [9] = 0;
        end
    end
end


always@(negedge clk)
begin
    if (!handshake )
    begin
        if(!sent)
        begin
            y=0;

            for (i=NUMCOEFFICIENTS-1; i > 0; i=i-1) //shifts coeffecients
            begin
                xn[i] = xn[i-1];
            end

            xn[0] = datastore;      

            for (i=0; i<NUMCOEFFICIENTS; i=i+1)
            begin   
            // Calculate coefficient based on the coeffIndex value. Note that coeffIndex is a signed value!
            // (Note: These don't necessarily have to be blocking statements.)
            case ( 464-i )

                12'd0: out = 17'd442;   // This coefficient should be multiplied with the oldest input value
                12'd1: out = -17'd373;
                12'd2: out = -17'd169;
                ...
                12'd463: out = -17'd373; //-17'd373
                12'd464: out = 17'd442;  //17'd442
                // This coefficient should be multiplied with the most recent data input

                // This should never occur.
                default: out = 17'h0000;        
        endcase

            y = y + (out * xn[i]);

            end

            sent = 1;

        end
    end
    else if (handshake)
    begin
        sent = 0;
    end
end     

assign YY = (y>>>15); //THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUE!

always @(YY)
begin

            LED1 = 0;
            LED2 = 1;

            if ((YY >= 40) && (YY <= 60))
            begin
                LED1 <= 0;
                LED2 <= 0;
            end
            if ((YY >= 90) && (YY <= 110))
            begin
                LED1 <= 1;
                LED2 <= 0;
            end
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: You have defined y as 32 bits wide and yy as 8 bits. You then right shift y by 15 and assign to yy.  You have the possibility of overflow if the MSBs of y are not all 0 (or 1 if negative)

Comment: Would that cause my number of gates to skyrocket though?

Comment: Nope, just trying to lint your code for other potential issues.

Comment: Good call. I'll be changing that.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly seeing the effects of **synthesis optimisation**.

The following line is the only place that uses `y`:

```
assign YY = (y>>>15); //THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUE!
```

If you remove this line, all the logic that feeds into `y` (including `out` and `xn`) will be removed. On Altera you want to look carefully through your map report which will contain (buried amongst a million other things) information about all the logic that Quartus has removed and the reason behind it.

Good places to start are the *Port Connectivity Checks* which will tell you if any inputs or outputs are stuck high or low or are dangling.  The look through the *Registers Removed During Synthesis* section and *Removed Registers Triggering Further Register Optimizations*.

You can try to force Quartus not to remove redundant logic by using the following in your QSF:

```
set_instance_assignment -name preserve_fanout_free_node on -to reg
set_instance_assignment -name preserve_register on -to foo
```

In your case however it sounds like the correct solution is to re-factor the code rather than try to preserve redundant logic.  I suspect you want to investigate using an [embedded RAM](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/hb/cyc3/cyc3_ciii51004.pdf) to store the coefficients.

Comment: I assumed `assign YY = (y>>>15)` was being replaced with `assign YY = (y)`

Comment: I have edited the question, I did in fact replace the "bad" line with the one above. Therefore, I'm still using y, just not shifting it.

Comment: @Radrider33 Since `YY` is much smaller than `y` a direct assignment will truncate 24 bits of `y` and thus allow the tool to optimise. The arithmetic shift will not discard the same bits and potentially use more bits to sign extend so the optimisation will be different. The answer still applies, however I would add that examining the differences in your logic using the **RTL Viewer** will help spot the root cause of the optimisation.  You also want to comb the map report - if your co-efficient table isn't inferring a ROM (either in MLAB or M9K) it will be hideously inefficient!

Answer (score 1):

(In addition to Chiggs' answer, assuming that you are hooking up YY correctly ....)

I would add that, you don't need `>>>`. It would be simpler to write :

```
assign YY = y[22:15];
```

And BTW, initial blocks are ignored for synthesis. So, you want to move that initialization to the respective always blocks in a `if (reset)` or `if (handshake)` section.

Comment: Really? So doing that assignment would effectively be the exact same as a sign extended bit shift by 15? Neat. I might have to try that. I'll also take care of the initial begin. Another useful bit of info that I didm't know.

Comment: Since you defined YY to be 8 bits, your original assignment was equivalent to shifting by 15 (filling in the sign into the upper 15 bits) and then extracting bits 7:0. So, should be equivalent to just extracting the bits that would land into 7:0 directly.